# Logistic loss increasing while training with minibatches using the adam algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression, optimization

I am trying to write my own code to use the adam algorithm for logistic regression. I am pretty sure It is training correctly as when I run it I am able to accurately classify a bunch of toy data that was generated using the parameters from the model. However, the cost keeps going up after each epoch and I don't think that is supposed to happen. Here are the two functions where I think there could be a problem:

```
def log_loss(mX, mY, params, penalty = 'l2', C = 1.0):

    #make sure y is the right shape
    mY = mY.reshape(-1,1)

    # get model parameters from dictionary
    w = params[list(params.keys())[0]]

    intercept = len(params.keys()) == 2

    if intercept:
        b = params[list(params.keys())[1]]

    else:
        b = 0

    mm = mX.shape[0]

    # compute model hypothesis
    z = mX.dot(w) + b
    h = sigmoid(z)

    # compute gradient
    error = h - mY
    dw = C * np.dot(np.transpose(mX), error) / mm

    if intercept:
        db = C * np.sum(error) / mm

    else:
        db = None

    # compute cost without regularization
    log_loss = np.multiply(y, np.log(h)) + np.multiply(1 - y, np.log(1 - h))
    cost = -C * np.sum(log_loss) / mm

    # now add regularization
    if penalty == 'l2':
        dw += w / mm
        cost += np.sum(np.multiply(w, w)) / (2 * mm)

    elif penalty == 'l1':
        dw += np.divide(np.abs(w), w)
        cost += np.sum(np.abs(w)) / (2 * mm)

    if db:
        grads = {'dw': dw, 'db': db}

    else:
        grads = {'dw': dw}

    return grads, cost
```

I am reasonably sure that the cost function implementation is correct. The function that trains the model is here:

def train_model(X, y, lr = 0.01, mini_batch_size = 64, beta1 = 0.9, 
                beta2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-6, num_epochs = 1000, 
                print_cost = True, fit_intercept = True, 
                penalty = 'l2', C = 1):

```
costs = []
t = 0
m, n = X.shape

params = initializeParameters(n, fit_intercept)
v, s = initialize_params_adam(n, fit_intercept)
num_mini_batches = math.ceil(m / mini_batch_size)

for i in range(num_epochs):

    minibatches = random_mini_batches(X, y, mini_batch_size)
    epoch_cost = 0

    for minibatch in minibatches:

        (mX, mY) = minibatch

        grads, cost = log_loss(mX, mY, params, penalty, C) 

        epoch_cost += cost

        t += 1
        params, v, s = update_params_adam(params, grads, v, s, t, 
                                          lr, beta1, beta2, epsilon)

    if print_cost:
        costs.append(epoch_cost / num_mini_batches)
        print("Cost at epoch %i: %f" %(i + 1, epoch_cost / num_mini_batches))

return params, costs
```

When I run the full program I get this output:

Cost at epoch 1: 15593.325359

Cost at epoch 2: 9042.439993

Cost at epoch 3: 9616.118761

Cost at epoch 4: 10005.095845

Cost at epoch 5: 10436.960861

Cost at epoch 6: 10914.245428

Cost at epoch 7: 11425.692792

Cost at epoch 8: 11959.885890

Cost at epoch 9: 12507.349951

Cost at epoch 10: 13060.884386

Cost at epoch 11: 13615.315131

Cost at epoch 12: 14167.092496

Cost at epoch 13: 14713.897392

Cost at epoch 14: 15254.310444

Cost at epoch 15: 15787.553480
...

and yet the model perfectly classifies the toy data. What is going on?

EDIT: I just tried lower the learning rate and that definitely seemed to help, but it still goes down for a while and then slowly goes up a bit. Could this be because the learning rate is still too large When we are near the minimum?

Comment: Have you tried to lower the learning rate? Usually it's the guilt for exploding losses

Comment: I have not but that is a good idea. I thought that when using adam, the gradient would adapt to basically any learning rate so I haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: If I'm correct, you us a LR of 1. Try something around 1e-3